# Функция в функции

Tags: c

Здравствуйте, подскажите, как изменить результат функции в другой функции? Сам код написал, однако необходимо  сумму цифр числа представить в функции, которая далее будет изменятся. Саму функцию я напишу, но вот использовать ее в след функции не знаю как. Все числа, удовлетворяющие условию, входят в бесконечный цикл, тк значение функции не меняется, как изменить, не знаю. 
А вообще задание вот: дана последовательность из n целых чисел. Для скольких чисел последовательности выполняется условие: сумма цифр числа является степенью трех.

```
**int a, sum;
        a = 0;
        sum = 0;
        while (x)
        {
            a = x % 10;
            x = x / 10;
            sum = sum + a;
        }**

void step3(int n, int *kol)
{
    int i,x;
    *kol = 0;
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        printf("Введите число последовательности x=");
        scanf_s("%d", &x);
        int a, sum;
        a = 0;
        sum = 0;
        while (x)
        {
            a = x % 10;
            x = x / 10;
            sum = sum + a;
        }
    while (sum%3== 0)
    {
        sum=sum/ 3;
        }
        if(sum==1)
        {
        (*kol)++;
    }
    }
}
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
    int k,n;
    printf("Введите количество чисел последовательности n=");
    scanf_s("%d", &n);
    step3(n, &k);
    printf("Количество чисел,удовлетворяющих условию - %d\n",k);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: А почему бы вам не использовать return вместо передачи по указателю?

Comment: Не знаю, мб я что-то не так делаю, но получается это [ссылка](https://pp.userapi.com/c831409/v831409535/19ea5/_IRmb-WL5IE.jpg). Т.е при удовлетворяющем результате, входит в цикл 30 строки и так до бесконечности

Comment: я так и не понял что и зачем вы хотите поменять? какой результат должна выдавать первая и вторая ф-ция?

Comment: Мне необходимо добавить функцию суммы цифр числа в другую функцию, которая определяет, является ли сумма цифр числа степенью 3. Когда я ее добавляю, то у меня цикл получается бесконечным, тк функция не меняет результат при вызове,как я понял. Поэтому прошу помочь сделать так, чтобы работало.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Маленько подправил то, что Вы написали:

```
#include <stdio.h>

// Сумма цифр, из которых состоит число 
int num_sum(int n) {

    int a,sum;

        a = n;
        sum = 0;

        while (a)
        {
            sum += a % 10;;
            a = a / 10;
        }
    return sum;
}

// Число является степенью тройки ?
int is_power3(int n) {

    int a, rem;

        a = n;
        while (a > 2)
        {
            rem = a % 3;
        if (rem != 0) return rem;
            a = a / 3;
        }
    // Если и последний остаток равен 0, то n - степень тройки
    return rem;
}


void step3(int n, int *kol)
{
    int ds, x, i, k=0;

    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
    // Вводим очередное число
        printf("Введите число последовательности x=");
        scanf("%d", &x);

    // Получаем сумму цифр
    ds = num_sum(x);

    // Проверяем на степень тройки
    if (is_power3(ds) == 0) k++;
    }

    *kol = k;
}

int main()
{
    // setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");

    int k,n;
    printf("Введите количество чисел последовательности n=");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    step3(n, &k);
    printf("Количество чисел,удовлетворяющих условию - %d\n",k);
    // system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Т.к. собирал программу под линукс, то Вам нужно вернуть к виндовозному виду строки: 44, 58, 62 и 65

Comment: Спасибо, именно этого мне и не хватало, разобрался)